# Having to update each INSERT SQL command after adding a new column in a database

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I'm a newbie in the websites development.

I faced a problem with adding new columns into a database.

The problem is about having to always update each SQL command that specifies a list of columns (such as INSERT, CREATE, ...) after adding a new column.
For example, I have a SQL command to insert a new user into the database:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `pass`) 
VALUES (NULL, $name, $email, $pass)
```

But then I add a new column `phone` at the end of the table `users`, and now I have to update all INSERT commands into this table:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `pass`, `phone`) 
VALUES (NULL, $name, $email, $pass, $phone)
```

I might have a lot of INSERT commands in a code, and I will have to update each one of them.

Is there a solution in the web development?

Hope for your help!

Comment: That's pretty much sums what ORMs are for. They reduce a lot of error-prone typing.

Comment: You don't have to update the `insert` statements unless you want to include a value for the new column.  And if you do, you would need to update them anyway to provide the value.

Comment: This really is a non-issue and smells like a common problem of just jumping in and starting coding rather than proper research, design and modelling. At the end of the day, if you come back to an application later and add a new column, provided all your existing inserts properly specify the names of columns, nothing will break and you only need to amend the inserts that need to populate the new data - which you have to do, there's no magic to get around that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I thought that I have to specify all table's columns in the INSERT command. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just leave the column out.  If `phone` is a column and you have:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `pass`) 
    VALUES (NULL, $name, $email, $pass);
```

Then `phone` is set to its default value.  If you haven't specified a default, the value is `NULL`.  You will get an error if the column has no default and no supplied value.

In addition, `id` is presumably an auto increment column, assigned automatically.  You can leave that out as well:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `email`, `pass`) 
    VALUES ($name, $email, $pass);
```